# Is it possible to save/share a link to a specific element in dev-tools inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It would be nice to be able to easily point someone to a specific place in the Elements pane of the Chrome dev-tools for some specific url. I can navigate to the url, right-click to inspect an element, and see what I want, but can I share that in a link with someone else?

Comment: Interesting thought I suppose...

Comment: Did you found something? Would like to add a link in the console tab to jump right into network tab to a resource I logged.

Comment: No, never did. Good luck.